# Ajuda - Upload Específico PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Galera, Eu precisava de uma ajuda enorme, na verdade uma caminho pra tentar fazer oque eu pretendo.

O problema é esse que eu não tenho nenhuma ideia de como fazer:
Tenho um sistema que geram boletos com o seguinte nome:

```
020 112.pdf
020 113.pdf
021 163.pdf
021 164.pdf

021 seria = id de um user, 
112 seria a quantia de boletos que o user tem até agora.
```

Eu precisava ter uma área específica pra enviar arquivos .pdf em apenas um input (file multiple),seja em php (Que eu conheço um pouco), ou outra linguagem pra mim estudar melhor. 
Ao Selecionar todos esses boletos acima, eu precisava que direcionasse automaticamente para a conta dos usuários.

```
Exemplo:
020 112.pdf
020 113.pdf
```

Esses arquivos pdf por exemplo deve ir para o user que começa com "020..." e assim sucessivamente.

Obrigado desde já.

EDIT:
Necessariamente só preciso fazer com que os arquivos fossem pra pasta de acordo com o código começado, como dito no exemplo.

Tenho o seguinte código HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Upload PDF</title>

    <!-- Google web fonts -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700" rel='stylesheet' />

    <!-- The main CSS file -->
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

    <form id="upload" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="drop">
            Drop Here

            <a>Browse</a>
            <input type="file" name="upl" multiple />
        </div>

        <ul>
            <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
        </ul>

    </form>
    <!-- JavaScript Includes -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.knob.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery File Upload Dependencies -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>

    <!-- Our main JS file -->
    <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>


    <!-- Only used for the demos. Please ignore and remove. --> 
    <script src="http://cdn.tutorialzine.com/misc/enhance/v1.js" async></script>

</body>
```

script.js

```
    $(function(){

    var ul = $('#upload ul');

    $('#drop a').click(function(){
        // Simulate a click on the file input button
        // to show the file browser dialog
        $(this).parent().find('input').click();
    });

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload plugin
    $('#upload').fileupload({

        // This element will accept file drag/drop uploading
        dropZone: $('#drop'),

        // This function is called when a file is added to the queue;
        // either via the browse button, or via drag/drop:
        add: function (e, data) {

            var tpl = $('<li class="working"><input type="text" value="0" data-width="48" data-height="48"'+
                ' data-fgColor="#0788a5" data-readOnly="1" data-bgColor="#3e4043" /><p></p><span></span></li>');

            // Append the file name and file size
            tpl.find('p').text(data.files[0].name)
                         .append('<i>' + formatFileSize(data.files[0].size) + '</i>');

            // Add the HTML to the UL element
            data.context = tpl.appendTo(ul);

            // Initialize the knob plugin
            tpl.find('input').knob();

            // Listen for clicks on the cancel icon
            tpl.find('span').click(function(){

                if(tpl.hasClass('working')){
                    jqXHR.abort();
                }

                tpl.fadeOut(function(){
                    tpl.remove();
                });

            });

            // Automatically upload the file once it is added to the queue
            var jqXHR = data.submit();
        },

        progress: function(e, data){

            // Calculate the completion percentage of the upload
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);

            // Update the hidden input field and trigger a change
            // so that the jQuery knob plugin knows to update the dial
            data.context.find('input').val(progress).change();

            if(progress == 100){
                data.context.removeClass('working');
            }
        },

        fail:function(e, data){
            // Something has gone wrong!
            data.context.addClass('error');
        }

    });


    // Prevent the default action when a file is dropped on the window
    $(document).on('drop dragover', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Helper function that formats the file sizes
    function formatFileSize(bytes) {
        if (typeof bytes !== 'number') {
            return '';
        }

        if (bytes >= 1000000000) {
            return (bytes / 1000000000).toFixed(2) + ' GB';
        }

        if (bytes >= 1000000) {
            return (bytes / 1000000).toFixed(2) + ' MB';
        }

        return (bytes / 1000).toFixed(2) + ' KB';
    }
}
);
```

UPLOAD editado:

```
   <?php

// A list of permitted file extensions
$allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif','zip','pdf');

if(isset($_FILES['upl']))
{

    $ext = substr($_FILES['upl']['name'],-4); //Obtém a extensão do aquivo.
    $nome = substr("020 112.pdf", 0, -4); //retorna o nome sem extensão
    $dados = explode(" ", $nome); //Divide a string em partes.

    $dados[0]; //Parte "0" da string corresponde ao id do user.
    $dados[1]; //Parte "1" da string corresponde a quantia de boletos que o user tem

    $dir = 'uploads/'.$dados[0].'/'; //Diretório para uploads separando por id 

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], $dir.$_FILES['upl']['name']); //Fazer upload do arquivo

}
```

Comment: Você pode usar o [explode](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) para capturar os valores `020` e `112`. E para enviar o arquivo... http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Você tentou usar o `explode` (como na resposta abaixo) para separar os valores do nome do arquivo?

Comment: sim, porém, ele até vai pra pasta 020/020 113.pdf, mas vão todos os arquivos pra essa pasta e não distribuiu para as outras criadas. editei o Upload

Comment: Você pode usar `$dir.$dados[1].pdf` e substituir `substr("020 112.pdf", 0, -4);` por `substr($_FILES['upl']['name'], 0, -4);`

Comment: Funcionou! Por um detalhe! obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue uma sugestão, existem inúmeras formas de entender e fazer o que você precisa. A "conta do cliente" pode ser um registro no banco de dados ou uma pasta específica.

O Html pode ser semelhante a esse:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Basic Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="file" name="arquivos">
          <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
       </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

O arquivo PHP que irá receber o `POST` pode ser semelhante a esse:

```
if(isset($_FILES['arquivos']))
{

    $ext = substr($_FILES['arquivos']['name'],-4); //Obtém a extensão do aquivo.
    $nome = substr("020 112.pdf", 0, -4); //retorna o nome sem extensão
    $dados = explode(" ", $nome); //Divide a string em partes.

    $dados[0]; //Parte "0" da string corresponde ao id do user.
    $dados[1]; //Parte "1" da string corresponde a quantia de boletos que o user tem

    $dir = 'uploads/'.$dados[0].'/'; //Diretório para uploads separando por id 

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivos']['tmp_name'], $dir.$_FILES['arquivos']['name']); //Fazer upload do arquivo

}
```

Dessa forma os arquivos deverão ficar separados por pasta, sendo que o nome da pasta é o id do usuário.
Exemplo:

- uploads/020/020 112.pdf
- uploads/020/020 113.pdf
- uploads/021/021 163.pdf
- uploads/021/021 164.pdf

Você deverá aprimorar o código, mas a ideia é essa!